# How to send an email with authentication "none"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send an email with authentication type "none". I have read examples about how to do it with basic authentication, but I don't figure it out how to solve my problem.

When I try to connect to an Exchange mail server I get a socket exception:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

I had wrote an unmanaged .dll in Delphi that can send emails, and in that project I had configured authentication type as *none*. So, I want to write basically the same in .net, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My program was rigth. .Net uses authentication type "none" by default if you don't specify any credentials.

A McAffee Enterprise antivirus installed on my pc was blocking me. Finally, when I deactivated the antivirus I could made work the program.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an SMTP server that you can connect to that also does not require authentication?

If you're using Gmail's SMTP servers then you must authenticate against them using your Gmail account's username and password.

Otherwise, we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials.aspx) its says:

> If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to false and the
>   Credentials property has not been set, then mail is sent to the server
>   anonymously.